# Using a variable inside context expression in GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, github-actions

Is it possible to use another variable inside context expression in GitHub Actions like

```
${{ steps.azure-secrets.outputs.$x }}
```

if `x=store-id` then the above should convert to

```
${{ steps.azure-secrets.outputs.store-id }}
```

So that I can use this expression and let it evaluate the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```yaml
${{ steps.azure-secrets.outputs[env.x] }}
```

Please check this topic - [Nested variable substitution](https://github.community/t/nested-variable-substitution/140291)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work :(
it gives the output as string `steps.azure-secrets.outputs.store-id` but not the actual value of the expression `${{ steps.azure-secrets.outputs.store-id }}`

Comment: I edited my answer - now it should be fine `steps.azure-secrets.outputs[env.x] `